# Are C labels instructions or constants

Tags: c, label, goto

I'm asking how are labels managed by C.

EX:

```
if (false)
label: printf("HELLO ");

printf("WORLD ");
goto label;
```

Prints WORLD HELLO on GCC
is it undefined behavior? (the label definition isn't handled as an instruction by the compiler)

Otherweise I'd expect some kind of error like "encountered undefined label"

Comment: They are neither constants, statements nor "instructions". A label is a special thing all by itself.

Comment: With that said, if you can avoid labels and `goto`, which you almost always can, then don't use them.

Answer (score 5):

Labels are neither instructions or constants.  They are there own construct.  However, a label can only be *applied* to a statement.

The syntax for a **labled statement** is specified in section 6.8.1p1 of the C standard as follows:

> *labeled-statement:*
>
> - *identifier* : *statement*
> - `case` *constant-expression* : *statement*
> - `default` : *statement*

In the above, the "identifier" in the first case is a named label.  Labels have their own namespace separate from struct/union tags, members, or other identifiers.  Labels also have *function scope*, meaning they can be used anywhere in the function where they are defined.

So your example (as well as the ones you deleted) are all valid because labels have function scope.